# redis-py ttl return None,But the redis doc refer to -1

Tags: python, redis

Why does python return `None` here when it should be -1?

[image: py code]

[image: redis-cli]

Answer (score 1):

If the key does not exist, [redis-cli indicates this by returning -1](http://redis.io/commands/ttl). For Python use it is more natural to indicate this by None instead.

You can see this has been intentionally done so, below code is from  class Redis in redis-py. The response_callback is called to change the TTL response from -1 to None.

```
RESPONSE_CALLBACKS = dict_merge(
    StrictRedis.RESPONSE_CALLBACKS,
    {
        'TTL': lambda r: r != -1 and r or None,
    }
)
```